# php5.2のsshでmysqlに接続する方法

Tags: php, ssh

現在eclipseでphpの開発を行っており、
php5.2のsshでmysqlに接続する方法が分からず困っています。

ss2_connectをソースに記載すると、言語ライブラリーの中にあるss2.phpを参照しており、
処理を実行するとss2_connectの定義が無いとのエラーとなります。

ss2.phpにss2_connect関数は存在しているのに、なぜ定義がないとのエラーになるかが分かりません。

分かる方がいましたらご教授をお願い致します。

Comment: 単に興味本位の疑問なんですが、なぜに今どき php5.2 なんでしょうか？　register_globals の悪夢がよみがえります。

Comment: 昔のsakuraサーバーで動作させているシステムなのですが、そのPHPバージョンが5.2ということです。

Answer (score 0):

質問の内容がよくわかりませんが、DBに接続するのならばPDOを使えば接続できます。
http://php.net/manual/ja/book.pdo.php